# Insert/Edit link modal text fields can't be focused TinyMce Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I have a TinyMce instance inside a bootstrap Modal.
When i click the "Insert/Edit Link" button, the modal opens correctly but the text fields are not focusable

[image]

The checkbox interacts correctly, but If i click the input fields, nothing happens. Ideas?

Comment: check  `outline` css property. _nothing happens_ means it is not focusable ? or it is not inputable?

Comment: @Jai outline is set to `medium none` but even disabling it nothing changes. it is not focusable and thus nothing can be entered. Links and checkbox work as expected

Comment: @Jai ok there is an event listener attached by jQuery which is blocking focus.

Comment: I have this issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @Pete yes, but I don't remember how, let me check

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I figured it out as well, I'll post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual issue going on here is that most modal systems (Bootstrap Modal, Magnific Popup, etc.) disallow focusing form fields that are not children of the modal. Since TinyMCE appends their dialogs to the `body` rather than the modal window, they're considered outside of the modal and focusing is prevented.

To allow the user to focus the TinyMCE dialog fields you need to explicitly tell your modal system to allow focusing within those extra dialogs.

**In Bootstrap Modals** (also [on TinyMCE's website](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:TinyMCE_in_a_boostrap_dialog))

```
// Prevent bootstrap dialog from blocking focusin
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest(".container-of-dialog-i-want-to-be-able-to-use").length ) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

**In Magnific Popup** (also [on GitHub](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/897), also [related discussion](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/280#issuecomment-28560156))

```
$.magnificPopup.open({

    /** settings **/
    callbacks: {
        open: function() {
            $.magnificPopup.instance._onFocusIn = function(e) {

                // Do nothing if target element is select2 input
                if( $(e.target).closest( '.container-of-dialog-i-want-to-be-able-to-use' ) ) {
                    return true;
                }

                // Else call parent method
                $.magnificPopup.proto._onFocusIn.call(this,e);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Obviously, as stated, you should replace `.container-of-dialog-i-want-to-be-able-to-use` with...you guessed it...the selector for your dialog's container. The idea is that the modal will *still* prevent all focusing outside of the modal, UNLESS you're trying to focus within the other 'acceptable' containers you've specified.

I'm not 100% sure if there's a *single* selector that will capture all TinyMCE dialogs that ever spawn, but for my uses--and I was specifically using this with WordPress's link panels--I had success with using `.mce-container, #wp-link-wrap` as the selectors.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I did it!

Comment: Very good answer. Saved my time. Just a short note, you can use ".mce-container" selector that works for all plugin popups.

Answer (score 2):

#### For Material UI Users

Howdy MUI users. Many of you will have problems with this, especially if you're using the TinyMCE editor in a MUI `<Dialog>` component. What you're looking for is the `disableEnforceFocus` prop on the `<Dialog>` Component that contains your TinyMCE Component. Like this:

```
  <Dialog
    disableEnforceFocus
    ...
    >
     <Editor />
  </Dialog>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me (focusin hit the bootstrap modal first), here is my solution:

```
    var modal = $('.modal:visible');
    modal.one('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        tinymce.remove('textarea.mce-small');
    });
    $(document).off('.tinymodal').on('focusin.tinymodal', function(e) {
        var dialog = $(e.target).closest(".tox-dialog");
        if (dialog.length && modal.find(dialog).length === 0) {
            var wrapper = $('.tox-tinymce-aux');
            modal.append(wrapper);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late to this post, but I want to share my experience to this question.
I need to implement react-bootstrap and tinymce for my project.
The reason already explained by @Pete: "bootstrap take the focus from tinymce."
In my case, I just need to pass `enforceFocus = false` in my react-bootstrap Modal component.

When `enforceFocus = true`: The modal will prevent focus from leaving the Modal while open. Consider leaving the default value here, as it is necessary to make the Modal work well with assistive technologies, such as screen readers.

Ref.[react-bootstrap doc](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-props)

Comment: how to implement this in React?

Comment: Could you specify your question? What do you want to implement in React?

Comment: I don't know JQuery, so I need vanila JS or React code for this solution (tinymce link dialog focus issue when used with bootstrap's modal): https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/bootstrap/#usingtinymceinabootstrapdialog

Comment: So, your question is to transpiler the Jquery code to vanilla js.  I think you should create a post about your question instead of asking in the comment and it may help people in the future. Leave a link to your question and I can help.

Comment: alright, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66212830/could-someone-transpile-and-explain-this-piece-of-jquery-code-to-vanila-js-or-re